# sonar-maven-plugin different results

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

I'm using sonar-maven-plugin on my local machine (with SonarQube version: 5.6.6):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</plugin>
```

And I have configured sonar on the remote build-server with jenkins:

Maven task:

```
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL clean package
```

In the console output I see:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli)
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.6.6
```

But i have different results (I have more bugs and Code Smells on the local machine with the same code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven tasks are executed in the order on which they're specified on the command line, and you are executing the analysis before the build.

SonarJava requires byte code to perform a full and complete analysis. If you're not providing class files to the analysis then you *will* get fewer issues that you should.

So under the assumption that some other process wipes out some or all of the class files between analyses, this is the source of your problem. Instead, try this in your Jenkins Maven build step:

```
clean package $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL
```

or as separate steps

```
clean package
$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL
```